# In Scala, what syntax rules apply to foreach(println)?

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

I am a beginner at Scala and wondering how this syntax works in Scala:

```
val numbers = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

numbers.foreach(println)
```

I know that the foreach method of collections in Scala requires a function as an argument, in this case `Int => ?`.

However when you write just `println`, isn't it equivalent to `println()` that returns a `Unit` value? Then isn't it a type mismatch? I can check this if I write:

```
val my_println = println
```

In this case `Unit` value is stored in `my_println`.

I can understand the code when the third line of code gets replaced by `foreach(println _)`, since `println _` is a partially applied function. But what rules apply to `foreach(println)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `foreach()` signature:

```
def foreach(f: (A) ⇒ Unit): Unit
```

And the `println()` signature:

```
def println(x: Any): Unit
```

Notice the the similarity between the `foreach()` argument and the `println()` signature? So `println()` can be passed in directly because it is of the correct type.

Except for: `println()` is a method and `foreach()` takes a function. They aren't the same thing so how does that work? It turns out that the compiler performs automatic behind-the-scenes eta expansion when a method is offered where a function is required.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler automatically coerces the method and uses eta-expansion:

Example:

```
class test {
    def m1(x:Int) = x+3

    val l =  List(1,2,3).map(m1)
 }
```

gets compiled into (simplified)

```
l2 = l.map(x -> this.m1(x))
```